# I lost my user and my home

Tags: login, users, home-directory, restore

Yesterday I started Ubuntu and when I put in my password at the login screen it said "password incorrect".

I ran the Ubuntu check disk utility and an error said "2 problems press any key to restart". How I can restore Ubuntu?

I tried reset my password because I think that maybe I lost my password but it did not work. When I tried to restore my password an error said "That user doesn't exist", or something like that.

If I start Ubuntu in live mode I can see my home in: `743 GB Volume/home/Quethzel` and my files are here, but I can't access it/them?

Answer (score 2):

**Enter Recovery Mode.**

You can follow the steps at [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), but I've duplicated them here for your convenience...

1. Switch on your computer.
2. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading,
   or has almost finished. (During this time you will probably see a
   logo of your computer manufacturer.)
3. Quickly press and hold the
   Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the
   Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB
   menu.)
4. Select the line which starts with "Advanced options".
5. Select the line ending with "(recovery mode)", probably the second
   line, something like:

   ```
   Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (recovery mode)
   ```
6. Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
7. After a few moments, your workstation should display a menu with a
   number of options. One of the options (you may need to scroll down
   to the bottom of the list) will be "Drop to root shell prompt".
   Press Return with this option highlighted.
8. The root partition is mounted read-only. To mount it read/write,
   enter the command

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
9. If you have `/home`, `/boot`, `/tmp`, or any other mount point on a
   separate partition, you can mount them with the command

   ```
   mount --all
   ```

**Move Your Files**

Just to be safe, move your files to a new directory.  Make them *readable by all*, so you can copy them back later.

```
mv /home/Quethzel /home/Quethzel_Backup

chmod -R a+rX /home/Quethzel_Backup
```

**Recreate Your User**

Finally, since you say your user is no longer on your system, you should be able to create a new user using the *same* name as your *lost* user.

```
adduser Quethzel
```

Enter the requested information and new password for your *new* user.

**Login Using Your *New* User**

Reboot your computer.

You should see the *new* user (Quethzel) on the Login Screen.
Type the password you just created, and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
You will see a *user added* message on the Login Screen, but you will have to click on the ">" symbol to complete the login.

**Copy Your Files Back**

After loging in, copy your files back. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and enter the following command.  (You will be able to copy your files because you had made them *readable by all* while you were in Recovery Mode).

```
cp -r /home/Quethzel_Backup/* ~/
```

Note, this will not copy your hidden folders or files, so your preferences and settings for some programs may be lost.  If you want to copy these back as well, type the following.  (Notice the "." before the asterisks in the command below).

```
cp -r /home/Quethzel_Backup/.* ~/
```

Finally, **once you are sure** you have copied everything to your *new* home folder, delete your old files.

```
sudo rm -rf /home/Quethzel_Backup
```

(By the way, you could also use Nautilus to copy your original files from `/home/Quethzel_Backup` to `/home/Quethzel` and then delete `/home/Quethzel_Backup`; to see hidden files in Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>).